# fill dictionary values in loop

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary `var items = [String:String]()`

Then I assign values :

```
    for i in itemInCart {
                items["param_id"] = i.modelId
               //items["param_id"]?.append(i.modelId!)
            }
    print(items)
```

I have just a last value.

I know that the method append() is not applicable to dictionaries, but how can I fill it then?

Comment: This is because you are replacing  `param_id` every time for loop `i` so it will always a last element you will found

Comment: It has to be "param_id" the key? Maybe you can use another key (like a unique variable from your Model) that it can't be replaces every time the code iterates inside the for loop as @PrashantTukadiya explained.

Comment: i know it, how can i append correctly first and second part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are replacing  `param_id` every time for loop `i` so it will always a last element you will found

You have two options, either create a unique key for each element (a bad idea) or if you want all the elements you have to create array and add it into the `param_id` key like:

```
items["param_id"] = itemInCart.map { $0.modelId }
```

so now your dictionary is  `[String:Any]()` or `[String:[String]]()`